# One bot managing many discussions with one user

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to create a bot who manage more than one conversation with one user?

I need to create a bot able to make the link between a random chat and telegram.

For example, if I don't wont to use Facebook Messenger anymore, creating a bot who send me every new Facebook message from my account to my Telegram number. The bot would create a new conversation for each unique Facebook user sending me message. Or, if it's not possible, a bot who create a new temporary bot for each new user conversation and give me his @name.

Is it possible with the Telegram Bot API?

Comment: Please explain more. Do you want to answer the messages sent from different users with one account using the bot and make it forward the messages to the related users???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the latest telegram bot api you can make more than one bot, but one thing that is crucial is **the bot's API token** **tha**t **is made manually through botFather**. You can make a single bot and make other bots inherit its features and every time a new user sends you a message assign a bot to him/her. Up to here, it's possible but for API token all you can do is to make as much bots as your Facebook friends count and store their api tokens in a DB and pass one of the api tokens to the bot that stands for a user.

This is what I think can solve your problem but the api token part is a bit strange  although you can send a notification from the main bot to your own account when the number of unsigned api tokens get less than 5.
As you know the number of Facebook friends can change and any of them at any time can text you so there must be enough tokens because every time one of them texts you for the first time a bot must be created with a pre-made api token and inherit the features from the main bot. From that moment that token and that bot stand for the person who tried to message you.

> Also I think there must be a limit to the number of the bots that you
>   can make using one telegram account which can be solved using
>   different accounts.

Comment: But freshly created bot cannot start a new conversation with me right ? I have to manually do it..?

Comment: Bots can send messages to users who has sent at least one message to them before. In your scenario, the bot is not going to contact directly with your friends it will use FB api and they will receive your messages in Facebook and for yourself you have to send at least one message to each bot after its creation and you can code your bots just in a way that when a new user sends a message the first message is stored and the main bot tells you that a token assigned to a bot with username xxx and you just need to send start to that bot to be able to receive all messages starting from that moment.

Comment: Of course after you send start firstly you'll receive the stored messages that belong to the time when bot was not able to message you and after that the messages will not be stored anymore because at the first try they'll be sent directly to you.

Comment: Thank you! Sadly it's not really practical. Hop telegram will improve this :-)

Comment: Yeah, Unfortunately for some unknown reasons telegram has not improved some parts of its api. Maybe it's one of telegram's policies. Actually if you have the sufficient knowledge of a programming language like C# this can be implemented by your own. For example you can have a unique windows form for each user and when he/she sends a message communicate  through that form and finally make the bot send the results to the chat ID or FB account the the form is related too. wish you luck 

Answer (score 1):

What you want is possible, as you know every single telegram user has a unique chatID in telegram so if your friends or users text to your bot directly you can use a code like below to answer their messages from your own telegram account and make the bot send it to the related user:

```
if(update.Message.Text != null)
{
 var req = new SendMessage(Your_Own_ChatID, "This message is sent from the user with chat ID: "+update.Message.Chat.Id.ToString()+"\n In order to reply it type the user's chat ID and add one comma then type in your text and tap on send.\nThe message:"+ update.Message.Text);
 await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
 continue;
 }


else if (update.Message.Text.Contains(",") && update.Message.Chat.Id == Your_Own_ChatID)
{
 string sender_chatID = update.Message.Text.Split(',').First();

 string Message = update.Message.Text.Split(',').Last();

 var req = new SendMessage(long.Parse(sender_chatID), Message);
 await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);

 continue;
}
```

But if your users send the messages from Facebook to you and you want the bot to send them to your telegram account and answer them again through the bot using Facebook API or something else, all that must change is:

Instead of sender's Chat ID you must save his/her Facebook username and reply it with the FB username instead of telegram Chat ID.

> Note that this code is just a sample and of course separating the Chat ID and the reply is a simple solution, but my recommendation is to use inline or custom keyboards to answer the message and that way you don't even need to type down the user's ChatID or FB account.

Also you can use telegram's reply feature and check if the reply is null and find the Chat ID(or FB account or ...) of the sender of the message your trying to reply and send the reply directly to that user.

Comment: I'm not sure you get my point. My goal is to separate message from different user in a different conversation in telegram. Each time a Guy send me a message on Facebook, the bot create a new conversation for this unique guy and I can chat with him like there is no bot

Comment: I got you mate and I posted a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

That is achievable using the method that is used in this project.

[https://github.com/idoco/intergram][1]

Essentially, you create a random userid for each user. In order to reply to that specific user, you have to use the reply to message method in your telegram client. Ie... right click on the message to reply to it.

Comment: Yeah, this trick is still working for me several years later 

Comment: The url is unreacheable